# CompositionTarget.Rendering doesn't like my event handler in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm converting a Windows Phone 7 app to Windows Store, so I'm moving over to Xaml. I have a method that runs at a certain point to update the data on the screen. It either assigns or removes an event handler delegate to the CompositionTarget.Rendering event. The message I get is No overload for 'OnCompositionTargetRendering' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler' '

Here's what I have:

```
    private void CheckCompleted()
    {
        Color completeColor;
        if (this.DecryptedText.ToString().ToUpper() == this.ThisPuzzle.QuoteText.ToUpper())
        {
            // We're done!!!                ...
            CompositionTarget.Rendering -= this.OnCompositionTargetRendering;// new EventHandler(this.OnCompositionTargetRendering);
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            ...
            CompositionTarget.Rendering += this.OnCompositionTargetRendering;// new EventHandler(this.OnCompositionTargetRendering);
            ...
        }
    }

    protected void OnCompositionTargetRendering(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        this.DisplayTime();
        if (ThisPuzzle != null)
        {
            foreach (UIElement thisElement in Letters.Children)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation `CompositionTarget.Rendering` is of type `EventHandler<object>` in [Windows Store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx) and not of type `EventHandler` as in [Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

This means you need to change the signature of your event handler accordingly to:

```
protected void OnCompositionTargetRendering(object sender, object args)
```

Comment: Oh.. object args... I saw the change in the documentation from private to protected... I'll try that, thanks.